# How to check if a string contains specific characters in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to count the number of sentences in a string. The sentences are seperated by '.', '?' or '!'. The 'text' variable in my file says: Congratulations! Today is your day. You're off to Great Places! You're off and away!

Yet, my program says that this sentence consist of only 2 sentences. I assume that this is because these characters aren't repeated (3x times a '!' and only once a '.')

How would I fix this in my code? Thanks in advance.

```
def number_of_sentences(text):

    count = 0
    special_characters = ['.', '!', '?']

    for char in special_characters:
        if char in text:
            count += 1
    print(count)
    return count
```

Comment: Your current algorithm is flawed... What if there was something like `Hi...` or `Hi!!!!`. You're trying to do this thing called [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) which is pretty complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` and a comprehension using `str.count`:

```
sum(text.count(c) for c in special_characters)
```

This isn't the preferred approach. Using regex is more stable:

```
import re
len(re.findall(r'\.|\!|\?', test))
```

Although why not just use the `str.split` function. Each sentence is separated by a space as it is:

```
len(text.strip().split(' '))
```

Comment: I like your first example, but the second example doesn't work if a sentence is separated with a newline.

Comment: I changed to using a space as the split delimeter.

Comment: I like the use of regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to leverage True and False summing like 1 and 0

```
sum(c in special_characters for c in text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement

```
 def count_special_chars(text):
    count = 0
    special_characters = ['.', '!', '?']
    for x in text:
        if x in special_characters:
            count +=1
    print(count)
            
count_special_chars('hi!!!!')
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your comment. Easy to understand as well

Answer (score 0):

Just do the other way.

```
for char in text:
        if char in special characters:
            count += 1
```

This is the same complexity since inclusion check is also O(n) for strings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It helped a lot. You mention O(n). Would there be a faster algorithm for doing this?

Comment: The overall algorithm is O(3n) = O(n) => you have fixed number (which is 3) of special characters and a variable length string. It can't get any better than O(n). Because you need to check each character in the string to determine the end of a sentence.